# MySQL Query With Combinatorial Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, combinatorics

Let's say I have a table with Columns A, B, C, D, E and F.
How would I query for entries `where (A, B, C, D, E, F) = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` but only a subset of columns need to match? For example at least 3 out of the 6 columns have to match.

The only solution I can think of is to go through all combinations `where (A, B, C) = (1, 2 ,3) or (A, B, D) = (1, 2, 4) or...`

But in this example that would already be 20 where clauses, if my math is correct. Is there a better solution, that also works with more columns? Or is my only option to programmatically create a huge, non human-readable query string with hundreds of where clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySql boolean expressions are evaluated as 1 for `true` or 0 for `false`, so you can add them in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (A = 1) + (B = 2) + (C = 3) + (D = 4) + (E = 5) + (F = 6) >= 3
```

Just in case any of the 6 columns is nullable, use the [NULL-safe equal to operator `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) instead of `=`:

Comment: Is there a performace penalty? With my naive approach I also intended to create indexes for each combination (in my use case it would be 15 indexes). Perfomance is more important in my case than a short and readable query string.

Comment: I don't believe indexes could be used in this kind of expressions. If performance is more important then maybe you should think about redesigning. Instead of 6 columns in each row you might be better with 1 indexed column in 6 rows with a common *id*.

Comment: If the conditions were based on fixed values, you could create an expression index. But the values must be hardcoded in the that index definition. If the values you're searching for vary, that doesn't work.

Comment: @BillKarwin There's a fixed set of values each column can have (roughly 30 for each column). They never change. I haven't heard of an expression index. I created all my indexes by `CREATE INDEX index_name ON database_name` which already improved speed by a factor of 50.

Comment: I mean you would create an expression index but you'd really have to hard-code 1 specific value for each column. I.e. not 30 for each column. I don't think this will help in your case. But if you're interested in general, the feature is called "functional key parts" in their documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts

Answer (score 0):

You can use a score system and then get the rows sorted by score. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*, 
    case when a = 1 then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when b = 2 then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when c = 3 then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when d = 4 then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when e = 5 then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when f = 6 then 1 else 0 end as score
  from t
) x
where score >= 3
order by score desc
```

Of course, this query won't be efficient in terms of execution time, but should work well for small subsets of data.